How to find the exact number of multiplications in nested loops with different ranges?
I'm working on analyzing the time complexity of an algorithm and need help calculating the exact number of multiplications performed. Here’s the algorithm I'm working on:
answer = 25;
for i = 1 to n-1
    for k = 1 to i
        for j = 1 to 2^i
            answer = answer * 8;
return answer;

What I've done so far:

I understand that the outermost loop (for i = 1 to n-1) runs ( n-1 ) times.
The middle loop (for k = 1 to i) runs ( i ) times for each value of i.
The innermost loop (for j = 1 to 2^i) runs ( 2^i ) times for each value of i.

Therefore, the number of multiplications for each i is:
$$
i \times 2^i
$$
What I ended up with:
To get the total number of multiplications, I summed up the number of multiplications over all values of i:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i \times 2^i
$
But I’m not sure how to evaluate this sum to get the final closed-form answer. I tried using a standard formula for sums of the form $ i \times a^i $, but I’m getting stuck at simplifying it to a clear result. Can someone guide me through the steps to compute this sum or suggest a better way to analyze this?
I was thinking of also saying the last term is $(n-1) * 2^{n-1}$ so its $O((n-1) * 2^{n-1})$ but im not sure if that follows and I also wanted an acc answer with no sums.

For algorithmic complexity, you only need a right answer to within constant factors (and ignoring terms that are smaller for large $n$). But you shouldn't have a linear factor alongside the exponential, and if you work outwards from the inside you'll see why.
